# Program to find fibonacci series of a1z,b2y,c3x,...,...,....,nnn using while loop in c?

Tags: c, while-loop, fibonacci

The series is mixed with multicharacters as well as integer, so What will be the code to print the output?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int fi=0;
    while(fi<=26)
    {
        if(fi>=97||fi<=122||fi>=1)
    {
    printf("%c%d%c",fi);
    }
    fi++;
    }
     return 0;
}
```

I tried this code but got no output

Comment: This line looks problematic: `while("fi<=26")` - you are testing the truth of a constant string, so you will never exit the `while` loop.

Comment: i edited the code and used ascii values of the characters as i was using int as data type but not got the result

Comment: `int fi='a1z'` and `if (fi>='97'}}fi<='122'||fi>=1)` are also problems. You may want to review your notes from your classes about data types. `'a1z` can never be assigned to an `int`, and an `int` can't be compared to a two-character constant like `'97'`. An `int` is a numeric (integer), while `'97'` is not.

Comment: In class they taught about only 3 data types in detail int, float and char as a fundamental type

Comment: which data type should we use here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `int fi='a1z';` here, you should use a counter that starts at zero and ends at 26.

You also can't use `printf` like this. It's not some sort of general-purpose formatting tool like it is in some other languages, you have *one* format string and the rest is what you want to print.

Here's probably what you want to do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int ctr;
    for(ctr = 0; ctr < 26; ctr++)
    {
        printf("%c%d%c\n", 'a' + ctr, ctr + 1, 'z' - ctr);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using while loop

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
     int fi=0;
     while(fi<26)
     {
         printf("%c%d%c",'a'+fi,fi+1,'z'-fi);
     fi++;
     }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int ctr;
    for(ctr = 0; ctr < 26; ctr++)
    {
        printf("%c%d%c\n", 'a' + ctr, ctr + 1, 'z' - ctr);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Issue resolved: we will not use single quote as 0 is not character.